# How to specify in Maven extra source/resource folders so IDEs are aware of them?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I'm a Maven beginner, and after some trial and error, I managed to specify different properties files for the release WAR with respect to the development WAR (I tried to do it in the simplest way I could think of, but feel free to suggest any simpler solution).

So, during development, my `database.properties` and `log4j.properties` come from `src/main/resources`, while producing the release WAR they come from `src/main/resources/release`.

So far, so good.

The question is: since I'm working with Eclipse, is there a way to say, inside the `POM`, that the `src/main/resources/release` is a source folder too, so that Eclipse will list it under the other source folders in the Project Explorer, even when another developer imports the project inside his IDE (i.e. without adding that folder as a source folder manually)?

This is the relevant part of my POM:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
...
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <war-name>/</war-name>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                ...
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies> ... </dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <properties>
            <war-name>ROOT</war-name>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <resources><!-- Replace Maven default resources directory (this could probably be achieved with a property)-->
                <resource>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/release</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it.

Basically, I declare all the resources folders I want to see in Eclipse in the default configuration (adding them in each profile didn't work since when a profile is active, the <resources /> node is appended to the final POM instead of (as I thought) replacing the existing one); then I tell Maven from which folder to copy the resources using properties, whose values are driver by the active profile.

Any comment is, of course, very much appreciated!

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>...</name>

    <!-- My prerequisite was that when working in Eclipse no extra steps 
         should be required to make the IDE use the right configuration than
         Configure -> Convert to Maven Project, so I didn't like having 
         default settings in a profile that must be enabled in Eclipse project
         configuration -->
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <war-name>/</war-name>

        <!-- These solve the problem: AFAICT, each <resource /> is added to the final POM,
             so declaring a resources folder in a profile didn't exclude other resources 
             folders declared in the default (i.e. without profiles active) configuration.
             So, the solution is to change what Maven brings in from each folder depending
             on the profile currently active. What follows is the default, no-profile
             active configuration. -->
        <res.devel.includes>**/*</res.devel.includes>
        <res.devel.excludes></res.devel.excludes>

        <res.local.includes></res.local.includes>
        <res.local.excludes>*</res.local.excludes>

        <res.release.includes></res.release.includes>
        <res.release.excludes>*</res.release.excludes>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources><!-- Here I declare all the resources folders, so that they will all be shown in Eclipse. Property values drive what is included and excluded. -->
            <resource><!-- This is the default Maven main resource directory -->
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources-local</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>${res.devel.includes}</include>
                </includes>

                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${res.devel.excludes}</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>

            <resource><!-- This is the resources directory for when the WAR is deployed on a local standalone Tomcan installation (useful for web pages editing) -->
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources-local</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>${res.local.includes}</include>
                </includes>

                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${res.local.excludes}</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>

            <resource><!-- This is the resource directory for when the WAR will be deployed -->
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources-release</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>${res.release.includes}</include>
                </includes>

                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${res.release.excludes}</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugins configurations -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Dependencies declarations -->
    </dependencies>

    <profiles><!-- Here are the profiles. When working in Eclipse no profile is active, so the resources will be taken only from src/main/resources (as per default properties values). -->
        <profile>
            <id>local</id><!-- This is for when the WAR is deployed on a local standalone Tomcat instance (i.e. outside of Eclipse) -->
            <properties>
                <war-name>ROOT</war-name>

                <!-- The resources will be taken only from src/main/resources-local -->
                <res.devel.includes></res.devel.includes>
                <res.devel.excludes>*</res.devel.excludes>

                <res.local.includes>*</res.local.includes>
                <res.local.excludes></res.local.excludes>

                <res.release.includes></res.release.includes>
                <res.release.excludes>*</res.release.excludes>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>release</id><!-- This is for when the WAR is deployed on the production server -->
            <properties>
                <war-name>ROOT</war-name>

                <!-- The resources will be taken only from src/main/resources-release -->
                <res.devel.includes></res.devel.includes>
                <res.devel.excludes>*</res.devel.excludes>

                <res.local.includes></res.local.includes>
                <res.local.excludes>*</res.local.excludes>

                <res.release.includes>*</res.release.includes>
                <res.release.excludes></res.release.excludes>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>  
   ...  
   < sourceDirectory > src/main/java </ sourceDirectory >  
   < testSourceDirectory > src/test/java </ testSourceDirectory >  
   < resources >  
       < resource >  
          < directory > src/main/resources </ directory >  
       </ resource >  
   </ resources >  
   < testResources >  
       < testResource >  
          < directory > src/test/resources </ directory >  
       </ testResource >  
   </ testResources >  
   ...  
</build>
```

Comment: That's how I *replace* the resources directory to make Maven pickup the release files, so I guess that's not what I'm looking for. I want Maven to declare an additional *source folder* so that the IDE will list it with the right icon in the Project Explorer. I'll post my POM relevant portions to make it clear.

Comment: build-helper-maven-plugin

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Although I didn't find this answer useful at first, it gave me an idea. As @Jehof pointed out, if you edit it to include a better explanation, I'll accept it.

Comment: After thorough tests, I discovered that specifying resources folders in profiles (that's the idea I got from your answer) didn't work. I posted the solution in my own answer. Thank for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the profile that eclipse should run maven in...

Right click on project, select Maven, and include the profiles you can eclipse to work under.

Your config should be picked up by eclipse when you do a maven update project (i.e. eclipse should recognise the new source folders) once you've changed the profile.

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see in the posted POM, I'm already aware about profiles. The point is that I need to tell Maven to use some resources when developing and some others when releasing, but inside the IDE I want to see all of them. However, @secret32 gave me a good pointer toward a solution.

Comment: Then in eclipse configure the project with both profiles...?

Comment: As a prerequisite I didn't want to alter the Eclipse project configuration, I like to keep things simple (most of all for others that may join the development), so if a step can be avoided, I prefer to avoid it. I just posted the solution I found as answer. Thank you for the suggestions.