# Maven. Nested properties filtering doesn't work

Tags: java, maven, filtering, properties-file

I have two property files:

```
#environment.properties
env = production
```

and second file is:

```
#commons.properties
production.port = 123
test.port = 567
```

Also,I have resource file which need be filtered by environment.properties file and commons.properties file and copied.
The resource-file contains:

```
${${env}.port}
```

So,I want to filter my resource file with first file and get:
${production.port}

and then I want to filter it with second filter file and get:
123

I use maven 3.2.5 and the resource-file isn't filtered at all.
I know that there's issue related with this problem:
https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRESOURCES-70 But it still unresolved.

So,my question is - is there any solution to resolve this problem? (actually,I think that resource-plugin should be modified for work with nested property filtering).

And second question - does exist any way to avoid this problem by refactoring,I mean any other architecture solution. Or, what would you do if you had same problem?

Comment: I managed to have separate configuration files in my project and to have just some of them in use at a time by specifying the active profile. See if you can get anything from [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25501962/3127111). Does that help you?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, watery. But my problem related with nested property placeholders. I.e. resource file should be filters with sequence of two property files.

Comment: Yes, I've read that, but that's not possible AFAIK. Is it a problem to duplicate the whole configuration in two separate files?

Comment: I understand,but,actually,it will be inconvenient in my case

Comment: It seems that's a bug and that it used to work in an older version. Good to know that!