# How to exclude configuration files using maven war plugin from dependencies jar files

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I have a maven war project. In this project I am including two dependencies like

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.softech.ls360.proxy</groupId>
    <artifactId>LS360ProxyAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>LS360ProxyAPIWeb</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
...
<properties>
    ...
    <tomcat-directory-path>D:\Basit\apache-tomcat-8.0.18</tomcat-directory-path>    
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.softech.ls360.proxy</groupId>
        <artifactId>LmsProxy</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.softech.ls360.proxy</groupId>
        <artifactId>StoreFrontProxy</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                <outputDirectory>${tomcat-directory-path}\webapps</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now when I make war file, then `WEB-INF/lib` folder contain other dependencies jars aw well as `LmsProxy-0.0.1.jar` and `StoreFrontProxy-0.0.1.jar` file. Now I want that from `LmsProxy-0.0.1.jar` and `StoreFrontProxy-0.0.1.jar`, I exclude all the resources containing `.vm, .xml and .properties file`. Actually in my `LmsProxy-0.0.1.jar` file I have properties file regarding web services and database. Similarly in my `StoreFrontProxy-0.0.1.jar` I have properties file regarding web services.

Now what happen now that when war file generates and web server runs then in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder there is jar. I need to open that jar and change my properties file and then again make jar file.

I want that my properties file are outside of jar. I simply change properties or whatever I want to change in my configuration files and that's it. Restart the server and everything is OK.

How can I do it with `maven war plugin` or any other plugin. I see `maven-overlay-plugin` but I think it's only for war type dependencies. I have dependencies whose type is JAR.

Thanks

**Edit
-------------**

LMSProxy.pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.softech.ls360.proxy</groupId>
    <artifactId>LS360ProxyAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>LmsProxy</artifactId>

<name>LmsProxy</name>
...

<properties>
   <maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.9</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
   <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.5</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>

<plugins>
<!--  uses maven-dependency-plugin to copy all dependencies to "target/lms-proxy-dependency-jars/" 
              folder, and defines the dependency classpath with maven-jar-plugin 
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeGroupIds>
                            org.springframework, org.springframework.ws, org.springframework.data, 
                            org.springframework.security, org.aspectj, javax.servlet, javax.servlet.jsp, 
                            javax.inject, javax.validation, org.hibernate, org.jadira.usertype, 
                            com.microsoft.sqlserver, joda-time, com.google.guava, org.apache.httpcomponents,
                            org.apache.commons, com.fasterxml.jackson.core, com.fasterxml.jackson.module, 
                            com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype, org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons, org.slf4j, log4j,
                            org.hamcrest, junit, org.mockito, com.jayway.jsonpath
                        </includeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lms-proxy-dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- To make jar file like a exe file, you need to define a manifest file and declare the application
             entry point inside via maven-jar-plugin in pom.xml. 

             - create executable JAR with the specified mainClass
             - exclude all .properties files located in src/main/resources from the JAR
             - add conf folder to the manifest, providing access to it from your executable JAR
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>

            <!-- The configuration of the plugin -->
            <configuration>

                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.vm</exclude>
                </excludes> 

                <!-- Configuration of the archiver -->
                <archive>

                    <!-- Manifest specific configuration -->
                    <manifest>

                        <!-- Classpath is added to the manifest of the created jar file. -->
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>

                        <!--
                           Configures the classpath prefix. This configuration option is
                           used to specify that all needed libraries are found under Lms-Proxy-Dependency-jars/
                           directory.

                           Use “classpathPrefix” to specify folder name in which all properties will be placed.
                       -->
                        <classpathPrefix>lms-proxy-dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>

                        <!-- Specifies the main class of the application -->
                        <mainClass>com.softech.ls360.lms.proxy.LmsProxy</mainClass>
                    </manifest>

                    <!-- Use “Class-Path” to specify the folder. “.” Indicate current folder, while 
                         “propertiesFiles” specifies “propertiesFiles” folder in same directory as JAR. 
                    -->
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>lms-proxy-conf/</Class-Path>
                     </manifestEntries> 
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- copy all .properties, .xml and .vm files located in src/main/resources into a conf folder in your project root. Note that this 
             step is an optional convenience for your users of the JAR. You can require the explicitly create this file in the 
             conf directory. This conf directory is effectively added to your runtime classpath via the manifest. 
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/lms-proxy-conf</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                    <include>**/*.vm</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Is `LmsProxy` a Maven project ? A way to do that would be to change  `LmsProxy` build and create another artefact (with maven-assembly-plugin) that does not contain the resources you want to filter out. You would then have a dependency on that new artefact in `LS360ProxyAPIWeb`.

Comment: @Tunaki Yes both are maven projects. Actually I have a modular maven project. In the war project I am including both dependencies.

Comment: Kindly check my edit. In my edit, I showed my LmsProxy.pom file.

Comment: I once set up a Maven project that had resources included or excluded from the final package based on profiles. See if [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25501962/3127111) can help you.