# Maven install lifecycle phase does not call the resources phase

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I have created a java project with maven. In my project (under src/main/resources) there are some resource files I want to be copied into target/classes.

I added these lines into my pom xml:

```
<build>
     <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

when I run *mvn resources:resources* by the command line I get the resources files are being copied into target/classes (so the resources phase in the lifecycle is working). However, when I enter *mvn install:install* in the cmd, the resources files aren't being copied into target/classes.

I get:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ mqm-data-population ---
[INFO] Installing C:\xxx\xlation\pom.xml to C:\Users\xxx\xon-12.50.14-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.278 s
```

it seems that the install phase in the lifecycle does not call the resources phase or something like that..

I thought that it might be rellevent to the resources plugin so I added:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

That did not help as well....

Can someone help?
Thanks.

---

SOLVED

---

After a quick search online I found out why the resource files were not being copied into my target/classes. I needed to use the maven resources plugin, and point out the phase in which I want the resources to be copied into target/classes (in my case, the “install” phase…).

After looking here:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

I added this to my pom.xml, and is working… 

Comment: Would you like to give a look at my [POM in this  answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25543585/3127111)? After a quick look, your snippet looks right to me (I ran Maven from the IDE, which I think equals to `mvn install`).

Comment: Have you tried running just `mvn install`?

Comment: First you don't need to define the defaults `src/main/resources` furthermore if you call `mvn install`  instead of `mvn install:install` which is completely something different. The first one calls the life cycle which includes the resources part whereas the the second one is just calling a goal of the appropriate plugin which does not run the life cycle. And you don't need the resources plugin cause that is part of the [default life cycle](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html).

Comment: I use maven with intellij. How can I use the default install (first option you mentioned)?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your default profile is not active modify it by adding true

```
<profiles>
<profile>
<id>development</id>
<activation>
<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<build>
<resources>
<resource>
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
<includes>
<include>**/*.*</include>
</includes>
```