# How to configure Maven profiles with different resources folders?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to configure my application to have 2 build profiles: development and production. In order to do that, I created two subdirectories under the **src/main/resources** folder: **src/main/resources/development** and **src/main/resources/production**. Each subdirectory has its own .properties files.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/development</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resource/production</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I build the app with the command mvn install -P ${profile_here}

Maven copies the content of the folder related to the chosen profile to the WEB-INF/classes output directory, however the development and production folders are copied as well.

WEB-INF/classes

WEB-INF/classes/development

WEB-INF/classes/production

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if my question and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25501962/3127111) can be of any help

Answer (score 1):

The maven-war-plugin is rather limited when it comes to resources. However, you could use the maven-resources-plugin to include/exclude resources like described here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html